# computer name of user along with ip address

Tags: php, javascript

hi i am trying to get the ip address and computer name of my users . i am able to get ip address but computer name i am not getting , i tried these codes.

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$_ENV['COMPUTERNAME'];
```

except ip address nothing worked for me. i want to get the client computer name

i want to submit these ip address and computer name in my server.or is there any better way to identify the returning visitor as ip address keep on changing every hour for most of the users . i want to count how many times a user from a particular pc is coming to my website

Comment: I think you can't get the computername... just the IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the computer name as the web browser doesn't send that to web servers.

Try using sessions:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to get the ... computer name of my users

You can't.

> is there any better way to identify the returning visitor

Use cookies/sessions, or a login system.

Comment: @Steeve: Why not?  Cookies are designed to solve exactly this problem.